# R function with two arguments if statement

Tags: r, function, if-statement

I am trying to write a function which takes in two arguments, and produces two results. The first function needs to compare an integer to 100, and provide "invalid" for text. This the code for that:

```
   compare <- function(x) {

   if (!is.numeric(x))  {
   result = "invalid" 
   }
   else if (x>100) {
   result = "Pass"
   }

   else if (x<100) {
   result = "Fail"
   }

   else if (x==100) {
   result = "Neutral"
   }

   print(result)

   }
```

The second function needs to prints "valid" if a character/text, and provide nothing if an integer.

```
   compare2 <- function(y) {

   if (!is.numeric(y))  {
   result = "valid" 
   }

   else if (!is.numeric(y)) {
   result = ""
   }

   print(result)

   }
```

My question is how to I combine these two functions into one? I've tried multiple things (not shown), but nothing seems to work. I need one function, called compare for example, which has two arguments like so:

```
 compare <- function(x,y) {....
 }
```

My problem is that I don't know how to combine the two arguments into one function block. The output should look like this:

```
 compare(10,"text") ===> "fail","valid"
 compare(100, 90) ===> "neutral"
 compare("text","text") ==> "invalid","valid"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this? Although I guess the desired output can be achieved in other ways as well.

```
compare <- function(x,y) {
result1=vector()

if (!is.numeric(x))  {
result1 <- c(result1,"valid")
}
else if (x>100) {
result1 <- c(result1,"Pass")
}

else if (x<100) {
result1 <- c(result1,"Fail")
}

else if (x==100) {
result1 <- c(result1,"Neutral")
}

 if (!is.numeric(y))  {
result1 <- c(result1,"valid")
}

 cat(paste(shQuote(result1, type="cmd"), collapse=", "))
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
compare <- function(x,y) {
  if (!is.numeric(x))  {
    result = "invalid" 
  }
  else if (x>100) {
    result = "Pass"
  }

  else if (x<100) {
    result = "Fail"
  }

  else if (x==100) {
    result = "Neutral"
  }

  if (!is.numeric(y))  {
    paste(result,'valid', sep = ", ", collapse = NULL)
  }

  else if (!is.numeric(y)) {
    paste(result,'', sep = "", collapse = NULL)
  }
}
```